# Select second row in group based on values in the 1st

Tags: sql, oracle11gr2

Lets say we have a table here, populated with the following data:

```
acc_id1  acc_id2  acc_grp_id1  acc_parameter1  acc_parameter2
111      111111   115          1               155
111      111111   116          2               166
222      222222   216          2               167
222      222222   217          2               168
333      333333   316          3               155
334      333333   317          3               169
444      444444   416          4               151
445      444444   417          2               166
```

Every account has multiple acc_ids, but the parameter codes are fixed. I am trying to retrieve only those accounts which follow this rule: if the biggest (latest) acc_grp_id1 has param1 = 2 and param2 = 166, both rows should be present. If the biggest (latest) parameters are equal to different codes, populate only the latest one.

This is how it should look:

```
acc_id1  acc_id2  acc_grp_id1  acc_parameter1  acc_parameter2
111      111111   115          1               155
111      111111   116          2               166
222      222222   217          2               168
334      333333   317          3               169
444      444444   416          4               151
445      444444   417          2               166
```

The actual output is a join from 5 tables.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: I noticed you have `acc_id1` `333` excluded from the desired result-set. Are you looking to base the grouping on the combination of `acc_id1` and `acc_id2` or just `add_id2`?

Comment: yes it should be a combination of acc_id1 and acc_id2, thats why in 4th example acc_id1's are different

Comment: also i forgot to mention, the given output is a join of 5 tables and consists from about of 30 lines of code, so i assume its better (more sufficient) to reffer the initial join once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this(not tested):

```
WITH FullData AS
(
    SELECT  a.*,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY acc_id2 ORDER BY acc_grp_id1 DESC) AS Position
      FROM  <YOUR-TABLE> a
), FilteredData AS
(
    SELECT  *
      FROM  FullData
     WHERE  Position = 1 
       AND  acc_parameter_1 = 2 
       AND  acc_parameter_2 = 166
)
SELECT  a.*
  FROM  FullData a LEFT JOIN FilteredData b
        ON  a.acc_id2 = b.acc_id2
 WHERE  (b.acc_id2 IS NULL AND a.Position = 1) -- Should be a.Position instead of b.Position
    OR  b.acc_id2 IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: can i use this "with" if this select would be wrapped multiple times in 5-6 other selects?

Comment: Chandu, this works fine but returns only 2 rows where second one has required acc parameters and omits other rows, so from my example above it shows acc rows 111 and 444-445

Comment: @user1324100: Fixed the query. Pls check it now.

Comment: well in this case it returns my initial join with no filtering

Comment: yes, this works fine, i just need one more filtering rule - if for two rows there are different acc_id1's (but acc_id2 are same), it should be populated no matter what kind of codes are in params columns (i showed that in the example but probably not clearly enough)

Comment: i believe i have to add acc_id1 to partition in FullData

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution:

```
SELECT
    a.*
FROM
    tbl a
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            bb.*
        FROM
            (
                SELECT acc_id2, MAX(acc_grp_id1) AS maxgrpid
                FROM tbl
                GROUP BY acc_id2
            ) aa
        INNER JOIN
            tbl bb ON
                aa.acc_id2 = bb.acc_id2 AND
                aa.maxgrpid = bb.acc_grp_id1
    ) b ON 
        a.acc_id2 = b.acc_id2 AND
        (
            (b.acc_parameter1 = 2 AND b.acc_parameter2 = 166) OR 
            a.acc_grp_id1 = b.acc_grp_id1
        )
ORDER BY
    a.acc_id1,
    a.acc_id2,
    a.acc_grp_id1
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c35fd/8/0)

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
SELECT AC.*
FROM (
  SELECT T.acc_id1,max(acc_grp_id1) maxacc_grp_id1
  FROM tbl T
  GROUP by t.acc_id1
) M
INNER JOIN tbl Last on Last.acc_id1=M.acc_id1 
  AND Last.acc_grp_id1=M.maxacc_grp_id1
INNER JOIN tbl AC on AC.acc_id1=M.acc_id1
  and ((Last.acc_parameter1 =2 and Last.acc_parameter2=166)
       OR ac.acc_grp_id1=M.maxacc_grp_id1)
```

Comment: so basically if i will have to reffer the initial join (tbl) more then once i could probably populate required rows separately thru union